# How to fix "Oh no! Your login temporarily failed" in Snapchat?

Tags: snapchat, application-error

Every time I try to log in to the app I get a message shown in the image below.
Yes, I've tried what the link tells me, and yes, I have tried the Xposed framework as well but no luck. I have a rooted OnePlus 2.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Did you try visiting the support page?

Comment: yes I did , i said that in the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Snapchat only gives out a login token without Xposed.

Uninstall Xposed, log in to Snapchat, and install Xposed again.

Comment: Tried that and it did not work.